# testing if statement which is not in function using enzyme

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, enzyme

I'm trying to get 100% test coverage but it says you have to test this `if` statment, so how can I do it ?

```
function Pagination({ currentPage, itemsCount, onPageChange, pageSize }) {
  const pagesCount = Math.ceil(itemsCount / pageSize);

  /**
   * ========> This If needs to be tested <==========
   */
  if (pagesCount === 1) return null;
  const pages = _.range(1, pagesCount + 1);

  return (
    <div>
      <Nav>
        <Ul>
          {pages.map((page) => (
            <Li key={page}>
              <A
                id={`number${page}`}
                onClick={() => onPageChange(page)}
                active={page === currentPage}
              >
                {page}
              </A>
            </Li>
          ))}
        </Ul>
      </Nav>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Pagination;
```

Comment: add a test where you pass values in props to get a page count of 1, e.g., itemsCount 10 pageSize 10

Comment: what did you try? Show the test code